# Disable VC for SVN in exclusive-locking mode

Tags: vc, svn

I have Subversion exclusive-locking enabled to increase SVN performance. If I commit a file the svn command line client opens Emacs so I can enter a commit message. But Emacs VC tries to determine the SVN status of the commit message file svn-commit.tmp with the command `svn --non-interactive status -v svn-commit.tmp`. That blocks because the commit command has the exclusive lock and I have to wait for the status timeout (10 seconds) until I can type my commit message. How can I disable version control for *.tmp files in Emacs to prevent that wait time? I didn't find an option to exclude files from VC.

Comment: Does adding `*.tmp` to `svn:ignore` help?

Comment: @nega It does not help to add *.tmp to svn:ignore, Emacs VC will run `svn status` for any file it opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override VC handled backends for specific file based on filename:

```
(defun my/find-file-hook ()
  (when (string-match-p "^svn-commit.*tmp$" (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))
    (set (make-local-variable 'vc-handled-backends) nil)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'my/find-file-hook)
```